# How can i create dynamically tab with viewpager in android?

Tags: java, android, android-tabs

**Explanation:**

Suppose, I have multiple categories which come from my REST. I don't know how many categories it's mat be 5,7 or sometimes 2 etc. I want to put all the categories on my tab with viewpager. I want to create a tab accordingly to the categories size. let's see e.g. suppose in my REST response have only 2 categories it's create only two tab. if it have 5 categories then 5 tab and so on.

Here is the sample test example to create a tabs.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        tabLayout=(TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
//            adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager){
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment,String title){
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Please, How can I solve out???

Comment: Hi @Milan gajeria i'm also facing the same issue could tell me you findings

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After you get categories size, you can add dynamic tabs as per your categories size as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;
Toolbar toolbar;
int no_of_categories=-1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    tabLayout=(TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    no_of_categories=YOUR_NO_CATEGORIES;

    for (int i = 0; i < no_of_weeks; i++) {
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB " + String.valueOf(i + 1)));
    }

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });


   }
}
```

And your Adapter Class should be like below:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    int mNumOfTabs;
    Fragment fragment = null;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        for (int i = 0; i < mNumOfTabs ; i++) {
            if (i == position) {
                fragment = YourFragment.newInstance();
                break;
            }
        }
        return fragment;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return super.getPageTitle(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: but the each fragment has it own layout file how can i manage them.

Comment: In you way if i change any layout.xml it's effect on every tabs.

Comment: If it is so, you need to have some flag with each category that defines which kind of fragment you need to load so that you can make those kinds of fragment layouts statically in your app to handle each different kind of category.

Answer (score 3):

if I were you I would try something like this:

its not a perfect solution just an idea of how you can do it, you would need to further modify it.

Create `number of fagments = total number of categeries` and name them like `fragment0`, `fragment1` so on to the total number of categeries.

and then get the number of categeries first lets say

```
int count = number of categeries;
```

and then add fragments to `ViewPager` like this

```
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    for(int i=0; i <= count; i++){
        adapter.addFragment(new Fragment(i)(), "ONE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

and to name the fragments i.e tab title you can make list of fragment titles, something like this

```
private final String[] title = {"One", "Two","Three"};

ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        for(int i=0; i < count; i++){
            adapter.addFragment(new Fragment(i)(), title[i]);
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

**For Kotlin**

After you get categoriy size, you can add dynamic tabs as per your categories size as below:

```
class CategoryActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var binding: ActivityCategoryBinding
    var numberOfCat: Int? = -1


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_category)

        numberOfCat = 10
        for (i in 0..numberOfCat!!){
            tabs_main.addTab(tabs_main.newTab().setText("Hello Fragment"))
        }
        var pagerViewAdapter = CategoryViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager,tabs_main.tabCount,str)
        viewpager_main.adapter = pagerViewAdapter
        viewpager_main.adapter = pagerViewAdapter

        tabs_main.addOnTabSelectedListener(object: TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener{
            override fun onTabReselected(p0: TabLayout.Tab?) {

            }

            override fun onTabSelected(p0: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                viewpager_main.currentItem = p0!!.position
            }

            override fun onTabUnselected(p0: TabLayout.Tab?) {

            }
        })

    }
}
```

And here is your adapter class:

```
class CategoryViewPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager, numberOfTabs: Int, title: String): FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

    var fragment: Fragment? = null
    var noOfTabs: Int = numberOfTabs
    var title: String = title

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        for (i in 0..noOfTabs){
            if (i == position){
                fragment = CommonFragmentForCategory.newInstance(title = title)
                break
            }
        }
        return fragment!!
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return noOfTabs
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return super.getPageTitle(position)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to dynamic tablayout and viewpager you can use this below code for a kotlin;

```
  for (i in 0 until tabLayout.size) {
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(tablayoutNameHere))
    }
```

This area if you want non scrollable you can handle use it;

```
    var tabLayoutConfig = Runnable {
        if (tabLayoutPrivilege.width < resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels) {
            tabLayoutPrivilege.tabMode = TabLayout.MODE_FIXED
            val mParams = tabLayoutPrivilege.layoutParams
            mParams.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            tabLayoutPrivilege.layoutParams = mParams
        } else {
            tabLayoutPrivilege.tabMode = TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE
        }
    }

    tabLayoutPrivilege.post(tabLayoutConfig)




val dynamicPrivilegeFragmentAdapter = DynamicPrivilegeFragmentAdapter(supportFragmentManager, tabCount,yourListHere)
        vpPrivilege.adapter = dynamicPrivilegeFragmentAdapter
```