# I want some logged in users two tab and some logged in users three tabs is it possible to hide tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want some logged in users two tabs and some logged in users three tabs is it possible to hide tabs.

Comment: share your xml code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create dynamic tabs as per the condition for which user you want to show two tabs or three tabs For creating dynamic tab you can [see here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38091002/how-can-i-create-dynamically-tab-with-viewpager-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

there are 3 methods implemented by the tab click listener, one of them is onTabSelected() put a boolean condition to check if your fragment is initialised. Then if that condition is satisfied then allow transaction to take place. Also initialize the tabs after your fragment code

try this

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the logged in user you will need to dynamically add fragments to your view pager adapter.

```
pagerAdapter = new YourPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragmentList);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
```