Viewpager and Tablayout inside Fragment with variable amounts of tabs
first post for me!
I'm programming my first Android app and am currently stuck.
I want to have a Fragment where you navigate through a TabLayout that's set up with a ViewPager. The fragment is meant to show details about an object and the amount of tabs should be variable depending on the amount of properties that are known on the object.
For example we have an object where some variables have a value and others don't:
class example {
    var a = "House"
    var b = null
    var c = "Garden"
}

Based on which variable has a value, i want to have a separate tab to describe said value further (in this case a tab called "House" and one called "Garden". I want to swipe through the tabs using the ViewPager but intended to reuse the same Fragment.
My approach was to make a list of the variables that hold a value. I tried to connect my TabLayout and ViewPager like this:
val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager, lifecycle)
        viewPager.adapter = adapter

        TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager) {tab, position ->
            tab.text = variableList[position]
       }.attach()

I seem to have trouble setting up the adapter though, as i get the error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3 . When I looked for help how to set up the adapter and tried to use other code I get a freeze and crash.
Is the problem that I want everything to happen in the same Fragment? Is there a way to still do it?
Thanks in advance!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38091002/how-can-i-create-dynamically-tab-with-viewpager-in-android

can you share code of you adapter ViewPagerAdapter.

You can find the complete procedure here https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view-2
